# React and Three.JS FBXLoader: model not visible and no errors in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, blender

I am encountering an error and I would like some help. I really do not have much time to fix this and I feel I have tried everything. I am a complete beginner in Three.js (as probably will notice), but I already dislike it somehow (my beach is back-end and math) and I am under a lot of pressure to finish this :/.

So I created a fancy pancy model on blender, and I tried to export it in a gazillion manners to three.js without much success. A plethora of errors and, at best, a dark screen. My last best in using FBXLoader, which gives out that lovely rich dark screen we've all learned to loathe, but I have tried the JSONLoader (I struggled with the .mtl file) and the OBJLoader&MTLLoader without much success either. Now seriously, I guess I am too desperate to focus on understanding this and discover the probably rather easy error that lurks behind this pile of litter. I would appreciate a knowledgeable, fresh, non-judging mind.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";

class ThreeScene extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        let THREE = require('three');
        let FBXLoader = require('three-fbx-loader');

        const width = this.mount.clientWidth;
        const height = this.mount.clientHeight;
        //ADD SCENE
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        //ADD CAMERA
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
        this.camera.position.z = 4;
        //ADD RENDERER
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        this.renderer.setClearColor("#ffffff");
        this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
        this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        //ADD CUBE


        this.loader = new FBXLoader();
        this.loader.load('scene2.fbx',   object  =>{
            object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                }
            } );

            this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            this.light.position.set(10, 10, 10);
            this.scene.add(object);

            this.scene.add(this.light);
            this.start();

        });

        this.camera.position.z = 70;



    };
    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        this.stop();
        this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    };
    start = () => {
        if (!this.frameId) {
            this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        }
    };
    stop = () => {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
    };
    animate = () => {
        this.renderScene();
        this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    };
    renderScene = () => {
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{width: "444vw", height: "40vw"}}
                ref={mount => {
                    this.mount = mount;
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default ThreeScene;
```

Comment: "A plethora of errors" what are they?  Put them in the question.

Comment: You should try loading your model to https://threejs.org/editor/ to see if it's displaying correctly. If it is, then you should separate your Three.js from React to better isolate the problem. Finally, you should post the errors you're getting with the code above. Also, have you followed the steps listed here: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models ?

Comment: Do you have `this.mount` in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Also, can you render just a simple cube, no fbx obj jsons etc?